Scale resets when entering vs code
When I enter in VS Code, the zoom level resets. What can I do to fix this problem?

I tried to turn off Mouse Wheel Zoom in setting, but it didn't help.
It's my settings.json file:
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Mariana",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.fontSize": 10,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.hover.enabled": false,
    "editor.renderLineHighlight": "none",
    "editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 4,
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
}

